# jquery form plugin redirect instead of printing response in html on successful php mysql script

Tags: php, response, jqueryform

Want to redirect to some page on successful login I am using jQuery form plugin to submit my form. Everything works but response gets printed instead of redirect.

**Login Form Submit using jquery form plugin**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Form submit via jQuery form plugin
        $('#formUserSignIn').ajaxForm(function(response){
            if(parseInt(response) !== 1){
            $('#flashMessage').html(response);              
            }
            else{
                window.location.href='/apps/home/dashboard';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**process.php**

```
    if(isset($_POST['btnUserSignIn'])){
    $userEmail  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtUserEmail']);
    $userPass   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtUserPassword']);
    $userPass   = $encrypt->hash_pass($userPass);

    $sql_check_user = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM workflow_users 
        WHERE user_email = '$userEmail' AND user_pass = '$userPass'") 
    or die(query_error('queryCheckUser', $conn->error));

    if($sql_check_user->num_rows > 0){
        $row_check_user = $sql_check_user->fetch_array();
        $userName = $row_check_user['user_name'];

        /*
        |-----------------------------------------------------
        | SET PHP SESSION FOR CURRENT USER
        |-----------------------------------------------------
        */
        // Set session name
        session_name('currentuser');
        // Set session expire time
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 7200);
        // Start php session
        session_start();
        // Store query result to session array
        $_SESSION['user_id']        = $row_check_user['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_name']      = $row_check_user['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_email']     = $row_check_user['user_email'];
        $_SESSION['user_pass']      = $row_check_user['user_pass'];
        $_SESSION['user_type']      = $row_check_user['user_type'];
        $_SESSION['user_status']    = $row_check_user['user_status'];
        $_SESSION['user_otp']       = $row_check_user['user_otp'];

        return 1;
    }
    else{
        $msg->set_flash_msg("Error", "Incorrect email or password.");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `echo` when you call ajax instead of `return`

```
if(isset($_POST['btnUserSignIn'])){
    $userEmail  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtUserEmail']);
    $userPass   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtUserPassword']);
    $userPass   = $encrypt->hash_pass($userPass);

    $sql_check_user = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM workflow_users 
        WHERE user_email = '$userEmail' AND user_pass = '$userPass'") 
    or die(query_error('queryCheckUser', $conn->error));

    if($sql_check_user->num_rows > 0){
        $row_check_user = $sql_check_user->fetch_array();
        $userName = $row_check_user['user_name'];

        /*
        |-----------------------------------------------------
        | SET PHP SESSION FOR CURRENT USER
        |-----------------------------------------------------
        */
        // Set session name
        session_name('currentuser');
        // Set session expire time
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 7200);
        // Start php session
        session_start();
        // Store query result to session array
        $_SESSION['user_id']        = $row_check_user['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_name']      = $row_check_user['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_email']     = $row_check_user['user_email'];
        $_SESSION['user_pass']      = $row_check_user['user_pass'];
        $_SESSION['user_type']      = $row_check_user['user_type'];
        $_SESSION['user_status']    = $row_check_user['user_status'];
        $_SESSION['user_otp']       = $row_check_user['user_otp'];

        echo 1; // echo 1 if success
    }
    else{
        echo "error"; // echo error or any thing else if there is an error
        $msg->set_flash_msg("Error", "Incorrect email or password.");
    }


}
```

Comment: I tried but `echo` gets the content printed instead of redirecting. Currently I am using  `echo "<script>window.location.href='/apps/home/dashboard';</script>";` on **Process.php** on successful `query_user_check` to redirect but that waits on **signin.php** page for a while then do the redirect but that makes it Improfessional.

Comment: dont echo script from php file. Your jquery file must be as it is which you have specify in question only change php file

Comment: Tried your answer but it prints 1 in result div `#flashMessage` instead of redirecting. May be I am doing incorrect check in javascript.

Comment: try checking after trim `response`